# Unable to install dependencies in AWS cloud9 for Cypress

Tags: amazon-web-services, dependencies, cypress, aws-cloud9

So I've been trying to install Cypress in AWS Cloud9. I did get past installing Cypress itself but not the dependencies outlined in Cypress's official website (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Advanced-setup).

I tried installing with yum, and get no package errors. I also tried using npm install, yum install, pip install, none works.

```
sudo yum install xvfb libgtk-3-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 --noplugins

No package xvfb available.
No package libgtk-3-dev available.
No package libnotify-dev available.
No package libgconf-2-4 available.
No package libnss3 available.
No package libxss1 available.
No package libasound2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted so that dev can figure that out and don't waste their time on solved problems.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, the package is called "xorg-x11-server-Xvfb" on CentOS5.

So you should be using the second option, "yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb". You can do "yum search xvfb" which gives you the proper name of the package, same thing you can use for other installations too.